# PHP Middleware Response/Request Params And IoC Containers

Tags: php

Having trouble wrapping my head around a few things when it comes to middleware in most frameworks. I understand the utility of executing in a pipeline ( authenticating permissions etc. )

What I don't understand is the need to pass response/request/next middleware as params instead of listing as dependencies for the class ( assume we aren't using closures ). Since IoC Containers cache classes after requested and pass references when "injected" wouldn't this approach be similar? Any change to headers etc. within middleware would still take effect without the need to worry about next middleware etc.

Trying to fully grasp the benefit of doing this vs executing a list of functions/classes etc.

Comment: then don't use framework, your problem is solved ;)

Comment: Trying to understand choices made by major framework devs this way I can have a better understanding of languages/choices made vs just learning how to use multiple frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

you middleware can update and change data from your request or response. So if you don't send the change to the next middleware, you will lose every changes you have done.

Using middleware this way, you catch the request, do thing, update the req/res and send to the next middleware. With this method, you can have other dependencies or lib accessing your req/res without a problem, and without you having the need to update this lib.

Comment: If each middleware lists response/request as dependencies they are passed a reference from container so they would receive w/e changes are made when a different middleware makes a change.